# Visual Studio 2003 is not working in Windows7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

My VS 2003 is not working. Whenever I try to create a new project or open a solution (created in VS 2003), it prompts me the following.

Visual Studio .Net cannot create or open the application. The likeliest problem is that the required components are not installed on the local Web server. Run Visual Studio .net setup and add the web development component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it you should *"Run Visual Studio .net setup and add the web development component."*

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the IIS is running. Also check the virtual directory of your web application.

Answer (score 0):

Do as the prompt says 
First uninstall your VS and then
  "Run Visual Studio .net setup and add the web development component."

Answer (score 0):

You have to install FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions on your IIS.